# Подключение SSL к Aiogram

Tags: python, python-3.x, aiogram, ssl, ip

Я решил сделать aiogram бота на веб хуках. Купил домен и SSL сертификат. Сделал всё по [этому](https://docs.aiogram.dev/en/latest/examples/webhook_example_2.html) коду, бот запустился но он не реагирует на сообщения/команды

Answer (score 0):

Проблема может быть в том, что вы указали неправильный URL для вебхука или не указали путь к SSL сертификату. Убедитесь, что вы указали правильный URL вебхука и пути к SSL сертификату и к приватному ключу. Если это не помогает, то рекомендую посмотреть логи бота и убедиться, что нет ошибок при соединении с вебхуком. Также можете попробовать отключить SSL и подключить вебхук без него, если у вас возникают проблемы с ним.

---

Чтобы подключить вебхук локально без SSL, вам нужно будет использовать ngrok, это утилита, которая создает туннель между вашей локальной машиной и интернетом. Это позволит вам разрабатывать и тестировать вашего бота на локальной машине, используя вебхуки, не нужно будет купить домен и SSL сертификат.

Чтобы использовать ngrok, вам нужно будет скачать ее с официального сайта и установить. После установки откройте терминал и выполните команду ngrok http 80, где 80 - это порт, на котором запущен ваш бот. Это даст вам URL, который можно использовать для подключения вебхука. Не забудьте указать этот URL в настройках бота в Телеграмме.

Обратите внимание, что ngrok существует только во время сессии, и каждый раз, когда вы перезапускаете.

---

Один из способов решить вопрос без ngrok - это настроить файервол или NAT на маршрутизаторе, чтобы перенаправлять внешние запросы на определенный порт на локальный адрес машины. Другой способ - это использовать VPN сервер, чтобы создать виртуальную сеть, в которую можно подключаться удаленно и обращаться

## Файервол (Windows)

Настройка фаервола зависит от используемой операционной системы и типа фаервола. В общем случае, чтобы настроить фаервол для перенаправления внешних запросов на локальный адрес и порт:

1. Открыть настройки фаервола. В Windows это можно сделать через панель управления или команду firewall.cpl в командной строке
2. Найти раздел с правилами фаервола. Он может называться по-разному, например "Правила брандмауэра" или "Разрешенные программы и службы"
3. Добавить новое правило фаервола. В параметрах укажите протокол (TCP или UDP), локальный порт, который хотите открыть, и локальный адрес, на который нужно перенаправлять запросы

## Файервол (Linux)

Для настройки фаервола в Linux также можно использовать различные утилиты, например iptables. Пример настройки фаервола с использованием iptables:

Откройте терминал и введите команду sudo iptables -L для просмотра текущих правил фаервола. Добавьте новое правило с помощью команды:

```
sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport <PORT> -j ACCEPT
```

Сохраните изменения, чтобы они сохранились после перезагрузки. Для этого можно использовать команду sudo /sbin/service iptables save.

## NAT

NAT (Network Address Translation) - это технология, которая позволяет сетям с разными адресациями связываться друг с другом. Она часто используется в маршрутизаторах и модемах, чтобы обеспечить доступ к Интернету для устройств внутренней сети. Настройка NAT необходима, если вы хотите перенаправлять внешние запросы на определенный порт на локальный адрес машины.

Как настроить NAT зависит от используемого оборудования:

1. Откройте настройки маршрутизатор
2. Найдите раздел с настройками NAT. Он может называться по-разному, например "Настройка NAT", "Перенаправление портов" или что-то подобное.
3. Добавьте новое правило NAT. В параметрах укажите внешний порт, который хотите открыть, протокол (TCP или UDP), локальный адрес и порт, на который нужно перенаправлять запросы.

Comment: Как подключить вебхук локально(белый ip) без SSL?

Comment: Дописал ответ на вопрос

Comment: Я как раз использовал ngrok, хочу сделать без него. Потому-что есть ip, домен, SSL-сертификат

Comment: @Nurlashka, примерно накидал.

Comment: Всё тоже самое, бот запускается но не реагирует на сообщения. Что можно ещё сделать чтобы это поправить?

Comment: @Nurlashka Дополните вопрос кодом и выводом